# Преффикс P и A у даты в PHP

Tags: php, дата

Здравствуйте, в некоторых датах встречаю подобные примеры, не понимаю что это за суффиксы P и A.

```
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('01 APR,01:55P')); // 2016-04-01 07:55:00
```

Я почему то ожидал получить `2016-04-01 13:55:00`

Comment: вы вписали руками в `strtotime` такую дату :D

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что предполагалось в тех местах, где вам эти аббревиатуры попадались. В конкретной примере - воспринимается как часовой пояс.

`timezone_abbreviations_list` возвращает среди прочего псевдонимы

```
    offset  hour
a   3600    1
b   7200    2
c   10800   3
d   14400   4
e   18000   5
f   21600   6
g   25200   7
h   28800   8
i   32400   9
k   36000   10
l   39600   11
m   43200   12
n   -3600   -1
o   -7200   -2
p   -10800  -3
q   -14400  -4
r   -18000  -5
s   -21600  -6
t   -25200  -7
u   -28800  -8
v   -32400  -9
w   -36000  -10
x   -39600  -11
y   -43200  -12
z   0       0
```

`p` - это UTC-3, значит `strtotime` генерирует метку времени для UTC `2016-04-01 04:55:00`. Затем `date` форматирует unix time с учётом вашей локали - видимо UTC+3 - и показывает `2016-04-01 07:55:00`.

Первый раз встречаю такие аббревиатуры. Не знаю, о чём думали составите списка и по какой логике так сделано.